# Android Emulator api level11

Tags: android

I just updated `android` from 2.3.3 api Level 10 to `android` 3.0 api Level 11. But I am getting these two problems. I have searched the internet but could not find anything helpful.

Here are my problems:

1. My emulator is in the portrait mode but my activities runs in landscape mode always.
2. The Application Launcher com.android.launcher has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: can you add your log info

Comment: delete the existing avd and create a new avd

Comment: I Have Created and Deleted many Avd's and getting the same results.

Comment: You mean the log info when my emulator is starting up ?

Comment: Just so you know you're not crazy, I've been able to reproduce this problem myself when creating a new AVD using the "Nexus S" device and API level 11. I suspect this is because Honeycomb was a tablet only release- it may not work with phone-based virtual devices.